# How to change a variables value using a method? Can someone give me some tips to improve my coding knowledge?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get used to Java. Been programming with C++ for about a year. I know the basic parts of programming Right now, I'm making a simple game, you select a number, two random numbers are being generated, if selected number is equal to one of the random numbers, you win and you receive some money. Casual game. Sadly, I'm not sure how to change variables value using a method. Could someone maybe improve my Java code and tell why my value is being recovered every time I keep playing the game? Sometimes, it doesn't even reduces my score value. It is hard to move to different programming language. Sorry for my language mistakes..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int money = 100;
        int moneyBet;

        int selectedNumber;
        int keepPlaying;
        boolean game = true;


        while(game) {
        System.out.println("Choose a number between 1 and 10:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        selectedNumber = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Make a bet:");
        moneyBet = input.nextInt();

        foo(money, moneyBet, selectedNumber, array);
            System.out.println("Keep playing? YES - 1, NO - 2");
            keepPlaying = input.nextInt();
                if(keepPlaying == 1) {
                    game = true;
                } else {
                    game = false;
                    System.out.println("Game over");
                }

        }


    }
```

```
public static void foo(int money, int moneyBet, int selectedNumber, int array[]) {

                Random random = new Random();
                int randArray[];
                int randomNumber;
                randArray = new int[2];

                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                if(money < moneyBet) {
                    System.out.print("Not enough money. Try again:");
                    moneyBet = input.nextInt();
                }else {
                    money -= moneyBet;
                }

                boolean checkWin = false;

                    for(int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) {
                        randomNumber = random.nextInt(array.length);
                        randArray[i] = randomNumber;
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print(randArray[i] + " ");
                    }

                    for(int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) {
                        if(randArray[i] == selectedNumber) {
                            checkWin = true;
                        } else {
                            checkWin = false;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                    if(checkWin) {
                        System.out.println("You won. You receive " + moneyBet * 2 + " money!");
                        System.out.println("Your money:" + money);
                        System.out.println("Keep playing? Y/N");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Try your luck next time..");
                        System.out.println("Your money:" + money);
                    }
        }
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Don't just give parts of your core method. We probably need to see the whole class.

Comment: Done. Theres only 1 class and a main

Comment: The value of money in the main method will never change since Java uses pass by value for all parameters

Comment: Consider having your make a wager method (?? `foo(...)`?? -- bad name for a method) return the value of money and use the value to update the key field.

Comment: Will do. Big thanks